# Drupal — staging version for content?

Tags: drupal

We want to replace our organisation's existing custom-built CMS and on of the systems we're looking at is Drupal (7. It seems to have a lot of the features we need but I am not sure if one thing we absolutely need is possible (either through the core or with a module). Sometimes we need to add a lot of new content to our website and publish it all at the same time. For example, we might have a load of new news items, new publications, etc, to be published on 1st September.

I can see that normally we can create those pages and simply leave them as unpublished until the date in question. But we might also want to update existing content (create a new revision but not publish it yet).

My question is, is there a way for an editor to see the website as it will actually appear once both the new content is published and the latest revisions of the existing content are published and if necessary make changes to that content (again without actually publishing it)? I suppose you could call this a staging version of the website, though not on a separate server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the revisioning/workflow modules to do this.

These allow you to set up a process or workflow for creating / updating content in a new revision while keeping the old content live until you are ready.

Some possible options are;

https://drupal.org/project/revisioning
https://drupal.org/project/workflow
https://drupal.org/project/workbench

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what we need, I think. And it's good to have plenty of choice.